# Can I add a local linux user to a supplementary active directory group?

Tags: linux, active-directory, access-control-list, groups

The Linux box in question is a CentOS 6.5 machine that is bound to active directory. I can change a local user's primary group to an active directory group. But i can't add the active directory group to the local user's supplementary groups.

```
# usermod -g ad_group_name testuser
# id testuser
uid=500(testuser) gid=1234567(ad_group_name) groups=1234567(ad_group_name)
# usermode -g testgroup
# id testuser
uid=500(testuser) gid=500(testgroup) groups=500(testgroup)
```

However, if i try to assign that group as a supplementary group, it doesn't work:

```
# usermode -a -G ad_group_name testuser
# id testuser
uid=500(testuser) gid=500(testgroup) groups=500(testgroup)
```

I can add that user to as many LOCAL groups as i want and it works great. Just not active directory groups.

How do i do this? I don't mind editing group files manually. However, /etc/groups doesn't contain any active directory groups. Only local groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding something.

When you assign the local user a `gid` identifying an AD Group, you effectively *map* the local user to it's Active Directory counterpart - membership of any other group is a property of the Active Directory group and its relationship with the user account object in Active Directory - not something you control on the client/member server

Comment: Ah. I see what you're saying. Not sure why i didn't see it like that before. I would need to add the user from Active Directory and let the client pull that information from AD.